# Order of execution in SQL Server variable assignment using SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variable-assignment, operator-precedence

Given the following example:

```
declare @i int
select @i = 1, @i = 2
select @i
```

Will `@i` always be 2?

This is about the most trivial example I can think of, but I am considering using this for swapping values in variables.  I also believe this method of assignment (select) is not ANSI compliant (however useful), but don't really care to have portable code in this case.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @MichaelFredrickson, we have @MartinSmith's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758032/880904) and reference to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx) on this.  I am now struggling with what the second sentence in this documentation means, exactly (emphasis added):

> If there are multiple assignment clauses in a single SELECT statement, SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the expressions. **Note that effects are only visible if there are references among the assignments.**

The first sentence is plenty enough to keep me away from relying upon the behavior, however.

Comment: Not sure this is even defined anywhere. I wouldn't count on any observed behaviour.

Comment: That's exactly what I am afraid of, so probably won't be putting this into production to just save a few loc.

Comment: A few LOC shaved is never a good reason. Having some thing work reliably and make it readable trump LOCs.

Comment: Don't worry, totally agreed. Still interesting, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For variable assignment, [Martin Smith answers this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758032/643591) referencing [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx):

> If there are multiple assignment clauses in a single SELECT statement,
>   SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the
>   expressions. Note that effects are only visible if there are
>   references among the assignments.

### But...

If we're dealing with tables, instead of with variables, it is a different story.

In this case, Sql Server uses an *All-At-Once* operation, as discussed by [Itzik Ben-Gan in T-Sql Fundamentals](http://books.google.com/books?id=v_T82PlI3UwC&pg=PT470&dq=t-sql%20fundamentals%20all-at-once%20update&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CFkdUZfGDOHFigLEqICgCA&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA).

This concept states that all expressions in the same logical phase are evaluated as if the same point in time... regardless of their left-to-right position.

So when dealing with the corresponding `UPDATE` statement:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    i INT,
    j INT
)

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (0, 0)

UPDATE @Test
SET
    i = i + 10,
    j = i

SELECT 
    i, 
    j 
FROM 
    @Test
```

We get the following results:

```
i           j
----------- -----------
10          0
```

And by using the *All-At-Once* evaluation... in Sql Server you can swap column values in a table without an intermediate variable / column.

Most RBDMSs behave this way [as far as I know, but MySql is an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693062/643591).

---

### EDIT:

> Note that effects are only visible if there are references among the
>   assignments.

I understand this to mean that if you have a `SELECT` statement such as the following:

```
SELECT
    @A = ColumnA,
    @B = ColumnB,
    @C = ColumnC
FROM MyTable
```

Then it doesn't matter what order the assignments are performed in... you'll get the same results no matter what.  But if you have something like...

```
SELECT
    @A = ColumnA,
    @B = @A,
    @C = ColumnC
FROM MyTable
```

There is now a **reference among the assignments** (`@B = @A`), and the order that `@A` and `@B` are assigned now matters.

Comment: +1, good find on the answer and near-duplicate question. I had debated acknowledging the column swap counter example in my question, but left it out for brevity.  Now, should I vote to close my own question?

Comment: @TimLehner I had a heck of a time finding the question containing Martin's answer... and the question you just posted was always at the top of my google searches...  I think that at the very least, this question is still useful as a pointer to the other question, and a slightly extended discussion...