# SQL assign variable with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question for following 2 SQL:

```
declare @i1 bit, @b1 bit
declare @i2 bit, @b2 bit
declare @t table (Seq int)
insert into @t values (1)

-- verify data
select case when (select count(1) from @t n2 where 1 = 2) > 0 then 1 else 0 end
-- result 0

select @i1 = 1, @b1 = case when @i1 = 1 or ((select count(1) from @t n2 where 1 = 2) > 0) then 1 else 0 end from @t n where n.Seq = 1
select @i1, @b1
-- result 1, 0

select @i2 = 1, @b2 = case when @i2 = 1 or (0 > 0) then 1 else 0 end from @t n where n.Seq = 1
select @i2, @b2
-- result 1, 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://rextester.com/IIGE73928)

Before the execute, I thought the case part should be `null = 1 or (0 > 0)`, and it will return `0`.

But now, I wondering why the 2nd SQL will return 1

Comment: Order of variables. Check [demo](http://rextester.com/JME74246). When you have `select  
        @b2 = case when @i2 = 1 or (0 > 0) then 1 else 0 end 
       ,@i2 = 1` you will get 1,0

Comment: I am more interested in the difference between these two: `select @i1 = 1, @b1 = (case when @i1 = 1 or ((select count(1) from @t n2 where 1 = 2) > 0) then 1 else 0 end) from @t n where n.Seq = 1
select @i1, @b1
-- result 1, 0

select @i1 = 1, @b1 = (case when @i1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) from @t n where n.Seq = 1
select @i1, @b1`

Comment: @lad2025, see my example. Not quite order.

Comment: Thanks the demo, could you explain more? The variable assigned before the `case`, then it should be `1 = 1 or (0 > 0)`.  But result of 2 SQL are different

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Intresting case :) Looks like some sort of short-circuit evaluation. I am quite sure that I saw similiar case in some blog.

Comment: I remember something about calcs in select and reusing variables. Let me have a look. That was something about all variables are set all at once and you cannot do that like you are doing it now.

Comment: Simplified: http://rextester.com/TPGLE50603

Comment: [The order of evaluation isn’t defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883930/order-of-execution-in-sql-server-variable-assignment-using-select), so I guess SQL Server just picks a different one with the addition of the subquery.

Comment: [Dirty Secrets of the CASE Expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression) - `CASE will not always short circuit` part + links to ms connect.

Comment: @lad2025 could you put that in summary to answer?  Based on [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics Of CASE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case) and [CASE / COALESCE won't always evaluate in textual order](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/690017/case-coalesce-wont-always-evaluate-in-textual-order), SQL will work on aggregate function first, as _Remark_ section in [Case](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql).  Seems that is the similar case for this.

Comment: @Prisoner Sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will post this as an answer as it is quite large text from `Training Kit (70-461)`:

> `WHERE propertytype = 'INT' AND CAST(propertyval AS INT) > 10`
>
> Some assume that unless precedence rules dictate otherwise, predicates
> will be evaluated from left to right, and that short circuiting will
> take place when possible. In other words, if the first predicate
> propertytype = 'INT' evaluates to false, SQL Server won’t evaluate the
> second predicate CAST(propertyval AS INT) > 10 because the result is
> already known. Based on this assumption, the expectation is that the
> query should never fail trying to convert something that isn’t
> convertible.
>
> The reality, though, is different. SQL Server does
> internally support a short-circuit concept; however, due to the
> **all-at-once concept** in the language, it is not necessarily going to
> evaluate the expressions in left-to-right order. It could decide,
> based on cost-related reasons, to start with the second expression,
> and then if the second expression evaluates to true, to evaluate the
> first expression as well. This means that if there are rows in the
> table where propertytype is different than 'INT', and in those rows
> propertyval isn’t convertible to INT, the query can fail due to a
> conversion error.

Comment: Actually I am not sure if this answers your question, but looks like it has something to do with this concept.

Comment: Yep, seems it's part of the answer, with "cost-related reasons", it evaluate the `when` statement first (with sub-query), then `case`, and assign `@i` in latest stage.  In the order SQL, as all "part" have same "cost", so it evaluate from left to right

Answer (score 6):

Just to extend @Giorgi's answer:

See this execution plan:[image: Optimization concept]
Since `@i2` is evaluated first (@i2=1), `case when @i2 = 1 or anything` returns 1.

See also this msdn entry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx and *Caution* section

> If there are multiple assignment clauses in a single SELECT statement,
>   SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the
>   expressions. Note that effects are only visible if there are
>   references among the assignments.

It's all related to internal optimization.

Comment: So why isn’t that the case for `@i1`?

Comment: I've extended my answer.

Comment: Basically, this Caution sentence is whole point and answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but seems not in my case.  By the execution plan (text will be better in this case), it shows that will execute the `WHERE` first, due to cost-related reason as Giorgi Nakeuri's answer mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Just to extend both answers.

From [Dirty Secrets of the CASE Expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression):

> CASE will not always short circuit
>
> The official documentation implies that the entire expression will short-circuit, meaning it will evaluate the expression from left-to-right, and stop evaluating when it hits a match:
>
> ```
> The CASE statement  evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops with the
> first condition whose condition is satisfied.
> ```

And MS Connect:

- [CASE / COALESCE won't always evaluate in textual order](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/690017/case-coalesce-wont-always-evaluate-in-textual-order)
- [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics Of CASE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case)

> [CASE Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)
>
> The CASE statement evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops with the first condition whose condition is satisfied. In some situations, an expression is evaluated before a CASE statement receives the results of the expression as its input. **Errors in evaluating these expressions are possible.**